# Do you know an awesome Python library for manipulating dates?

Tags: python, date-parsing

I search an awesome Python library date like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). Do you know some?

I want especially a library that can do conversions like this: *09/25/2012 00:00 - 09/25/2012 13:00* to *09/25/2012 00:00 - 13:00*.

Answer (score 4):

Some Python libraries inspired by Moment.js:

- [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)
- [moment](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moment/0.0.14)

Arrow and Delorean seem a bit more mature, although I have not really used any of them extensively.

Answer (score 1):

[datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) is as good as it gets. See it action [here](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html)

Answer (score 1):

[datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) and it comes with the standard library. And [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/datetime/) is Doug Hellman's introduction to the "module of the week".

Answer (score 1):

You can try these 3rd party packages:

- [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)
- [mxDatetime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/) : its parser is pretty good. Check whether the license works for you, though.

Comment: Can we parse dates range with them? For example, can they transform 09/25/2012 00:00 - 09/25/2012 13:00 to 09/25/2012 00:00 - 13:00?

Comment: you can use moment .step -1 Install moment package. step 2 momemt.now() and play any date manipulation https://github.com/zachwill/moment